# fastJSON generic object dictionary serialization

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, serialization

I have a bit of a strange problem, maybe there is a better solution so i will explain the whole situation.

I'm working on a blueprint editor for an Entity Component System i am creating, this is just a way for people/me to save a whole load of components and their settings to be loaded onto an entity at a later date in the game (Think Prefab from unity). In the end I'm trying to serialize a Dictionary< Type, Dictionary< string, object >> and i think this is causing errors in the serializer because of the generic 'object'.

To do this i have a wrapper class which is a Dictionary< string, ToggleBlueprint >, where the string is the name of the blueprint, and the ToggleBlueprint is struct which holds a blueprint and a bool value (To save if the children of that blueprint should be shown in the Hierarchy).

A Blueprint is made up of an AttributeTable, ComponentTable, List< string > for the list of children, and a string for the parent. This is where im not sure if i should change my design. The component table is a list of components, with a corresponding boolean value (Whether the settings should be shown in the editor).

This Attribute table is the Dictionary< Type, Dictionary< string, object >>. The type is the component, the string is the name of the variable, and the object is the value. The reason for this design is so that an attribute table can easily be made in code to further modify settings in game (Something that can't be predetermined or changes based on a very specific condition). I realize this probably isn't very efficient and this is the cause for my problems i believe, but i can't think of any other way to keep it so settings can be modified in game (On creation. Basically i made it so i could apply a separate attribute table over the top of the blueprint).

I'm wondering if anyone knows how to effectively serialize a Dictionary< string, object > using fastJSON (Or any other JSON serializer for that fact). At the moment i am getting a cannot cast from source type to destination type error.

If not, do you think it would work if i removed the componentTable and AttributeTable and just merged it into a list of actual component objects? (I'm assuming just serializing an object of a specific type would work smoothly)

Note: I have gotten something that works using XML, but this is bloated, very slow and prone to errors.

Comment: Look for JIL serializer

Comment: Im looking into it, pretty hopeful for it to work, but i'm encountering 1 problem... Cause i'm using unity, my project is stuck to .Net Framework 3.5, but the JIL Files are for .Net 4.5. Do you happen to know where to find a link to an older version perhaps?